# Scala case class copy doesn't always work with `_` existential type

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference, case-class, existential-type

I'm trying to `copy()` a Scala case class which has a type param. At the call site, the type of the value is `Foo[_]`.

This compiles as expected:

```scala
case class Foo[A](id: String, name: String, v1: Bar[A])
case class Bar[A](v: A)

val foo: Foo[_] = Foo[Int]("foo1", "Foo 1", Bar[Int](1))

foo.copy(id = "foo1.1")
```

But if I add another member of type `Bar[A]`, it doesn't compile anymore:

```scala
case class Foo[A](id: String, name: String, v1: Bar[A], v2: Bar[A])
case class Bar[A](v: A)

val foo: Foo[_] = Foo[Int]("foo1", "Foo 1", Bar[Int](1), Bar[Int](2))

foo.copy(id = "foo1.1") // compile error, see below
```

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Playground.Bar[_$1]
 required: Playground.Bar[Any]
Note: _$1 <: Any, but class Bar is invariant in type A.
You may wish to define A as +A instead. (SLS 4.5)
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/R4DaedcSSoWiB07otqLpGQ)

So far I found two workarounds:

- Make `Bar` covariant in `A`, then the problem hides itself because now `Bar[_$1] <: Bar[Any]`
- Define a `copyId(newId: String) = copy(id = newId)` method on `Foo` and call that instead, then we aren't calling `copy` on a value of type `Foo[_]`.

However, neither of those are really feasible for my use case, `Bar` should be invariant, and I have too many different `copy` calls on `Foo[_]` instances to make `copyThisAndThat` methods for them all.

I guess my real question is, why is Scala behaving this way? Seems like a bug tbh.

Comment: What is the point of having a type parameter if you are going to forget about it latter? Maybe you can redesign some part of your model to fix this problem.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I minimized the use case for compactness. I am only "forgetting" about the type param in contexts where I'm updating members that have nothing to do with that type parameter, such as `id` or `name`. I usually don't have any information available to me about the type param in such cases, thus the existential type at call site. But I do need the type param in other contexts when actually working with `v1` and `v2` members.

Comment: Why not having two case classes, one for the info that is not generic and the other for the generics. And a third class that composes of those two?

Comment: Because I don't want three classes where my domain says there should be one entity? I don't want to create meaningless classes just to get around a compiler quirk.

Comment: Well the compiler quirk was really the existential in the first place _(e.g. `Foo[_]`)_ those are tricky and will be reworked in **Scala 3**. One entity can be composed of may entities, it is really not that different for saying your case class has n fields. Also, you mentioned that you have a long code path were you do not care about the other fields, that is a good indication that you actually have more entities than one. Anyways, I just proposed a simple workaround, if you prefer to do a strange pattern match everywhere go ahead :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the compiler handles named and default parameters, the calls become

```
foo.copy("foo1.1", foo.name, foo.v1)
```

and

```
foo.copy("foo1.1", foo.name, foo.v1, foo.v2)
```

respectively. Or, if you replace the parameters with types,

```
foo.copy[?](String, String, Bar[_])
```

and

```
foo.copy[?](String, String, Bar[_], Bar[_])
```

`?` is the type parameter of `copy` which has to inferred. In the first case the compiler basically says "`?` is the type parameter of `Bar[_]`, even if I don't know what that is".

In the second case the type parameters of two `Bar[_]` must really be the same, but that information is lost by the time the compiler is inferring `?`; they are just `Bar[_]`, and not something like `Bar[foo's unknown type parameter]`. So e.g. "`?` is the type parameter of first `Bar[_]`, even if I don't know what that is" won't work because so far as the compiler knows, the second `Bar[_]` could be different.

It isn't a bug in the sense that it follows the language specification; and changing the specification to allow this would take significant effort and make both it and the compiler more complicated. It may not be a good trade-off for such a relatively rare case.

Another workaround is to use type variable pattern to temporarily give a name to `_`:

```
foo match { case foo: Foo[a] => foo.copy(id = "foo1.1") }
```

The compiler now sees that `foo.v1` and `foo.v2` are both `Bar[a]` and so the result of `copy` is `Foo[a]`. After leaving the `case` branch it becomes `Foo[_]`.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Makes sense now. I should be able to make use of that `match` trick in some of my uses cases at least.