# Behaviour of context bounds and implicit parameter lists with regards to path dependent types

Tags: scala, type-inference, implicit, path-dependent-type, type-projection

I always thought that context bounds and implicit parameter lists behaved exactly the same, but apparently not.

In the example below, I expect `summon1[Int]` and `summon2[Int]` to return the same type, but they don't. I expected `summon2[Int]` to return a path dependent type, but instead it gives me a type projection. Why?

```scala
Welcome to the Ammonite Repl 2.2.0 (Scala 2.13.3 Java 11.0.2)
@ trait Foo[A] {
    type B
    def value: B
  }
defined trait Foo

@ implicit def fooInt = new Foo[Int] {
      override type B = String
      override def value = "Hey!"
    }
defined function fooInt

@ implicit def fooString = new Foo[String] {
      override type B = Boolean
      override def value = true
    }
defined function fooString

@ def summon1[T](implicit f: Foo[T]) = f.value
defined function summon1

@ def summon2[T: Foo] = implicitly[Foo[T]].value
defined function summon2

@ summon1[Int]
res5: String = "Hey!"

@ summon2[Int]
res6: Foo[Int]#B = "Hey!"

@
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is primarily not in the difference of context bound vs. implicit parameter (<strike>there shouldn't be any difference</strike> (*)), the thing is that `implicitly` can break type of implicit found

https://typelevel.org/blog/2014/01/18/implicitly_existential.html

If you fix `summon2` using custom materializer this will work as expected

```
def materializeFoo[T](implicit f: Foo[T]): Foo[T] { type B = f.B } = f

def summon2[T: Foo] = materializeFoo[T].value

summon2[Int]
// val res: String = Hey!
```

It's intersting that `shapeless.the` doesn't help

```
def summon2[T: Foo] = the[Foo[T]].value

summon2[Int]
// val res: Foo[Int]#B = Hey!
```

Also in Scala 2.13 you can use more general form of materializer (not specific for `Foo`) returning singleton type (like it's [done](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/master/library/src/scala/runtime/stdLibPatches/Predef.scala#L29-L34) in Scala 3)

```
def materialize[A](implicit f: A): f.type = f

def summon2[T: Foo] = materialize[Foo[T]].value

val y = summon2[Int]
// val res: String = Hey!
```

---

(*) Well, there is a difference that if you don't introduce parameter name `f` you can't refer to the type `f.B` explicitly in the return type. And if you don't specify return type explicitly, as we can see such type `f.B` can't be inferred because of the lack of a [stable](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#paths) prefix `f` (see also [Aux-pattern usage compiles without inferring an appropriate type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64672950/aux-pattern-usage-compiles-without-inferring-an-appropriate-type)).

Comment: Ah, I see. So in other words, `summon1` works because there is a path to the type, via the `f` handle, but in `summon2` there isn't. Got it 

Comment: @gogstad note that in general _(of course there are exceptions)_ having implicit values and methods without explicit return types is considered a bad practice. Having explicit return types can help inference and avoid introducing bugs with changes.